# ask about the differences between datagrid from different namespace

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

is datagrid from System.Windows.Form and System.Windows.Control is different?.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid` is used in WinForms, `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid` is used in WPF (and Silverlight).